# Use nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

Currently I try to figure out how nested callbacks do work in Javascript. But on my example the console does not print anything. The example is pretty basic- should print letters: abc.

### Code

```js
function getA() {
  return setTimeout(() => 'a', 1000);
}

function getB() {
  return setTimeout(() => 'b', 2000);
}

function getC() {
  return setTimeout(() => 'c', 3000);
}

function handleWithCallback(callback1, callback2, callback3) {
  callback1(a =>
    callback2(b =>
      callback3(c => console.log(a + b + c))
    )
  );
}

handleWithCallback(getA, getB, getC);
```

Comment: setTimeout returns a number. Not a function- Look into promises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `handleWithCallback` you call the `callback` functions by passing arguments, but notice how your actual `getX` callback functions don't use that argument. They should take a callback function as argument and call it.

NB: I reduced the timeout delays so you don't have to wait that long to see the result :)

```js
function getA(cb) {
  return setTimeout(() => cb('a'), 100);
}

function getB(cb) {
  return setTimeout(() => cb('b'), 200);
}

function getC(cb) {
  return setTimeout(() => cb('c'), 300);
}

function handleWithCallback(callback1, callback2, callback3) {
  callback1(a =>
    callback2(b =>
      callback3(c => console.log(a + b + c))
    )
  );
}

handleWithCallback(getA, getB, getC);
```